# TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance

Tags: reactjs, promise, redux

I'm new in this project and I'm trying to use the `react-redux-universal-hot-example` API, but using my code:

```
export function showMessage() {
  return {
    type: SHOW_MESSAGE,
    promise: (client) => client.get('/posts')
  };
}
```

I get this error in my browser:

`TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced with the same issue and looking I found that was a typo.
you should use types instead of type
i.e:

```
export function showMessage() {
  return {
    types: [MESSAGE_FETCH, MESSAGE_FETCH_SUCCESS, MESSAGE_FETCH_FAIL],
    promise: (client) => client.get('/post')
  }
}
```

Bear in mind that the array of 'types' will dispatch those action(success or fail) when the promise will be resolved.

Answer (score 8):

if you are having this issue while working with es6 version of For Of loop, just check wheather you used **.entries()** on the array or not.

Example:

```
for( const [item. index] of arr.entries() ) {
 console.log(index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Solution:1  :-(if type having multiple values then putt types not type )

Solution: 2:- If type having multiple values then putt types and Order 
[XXXXXX_FETCH, XXXXXX_FETCH_SUCCESS, XXXXXX_FETCH_ERROR  ]

Solution:3  :-(if type having single value then putt type not types )